# Calculating the correlation between various columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have the following matrix `mat` in R:

```
      x  y  z
rowA -1  1  2
rowB -1 -2 -1
rowC  2  1 -1
```

How do I calculate the correlation between various columns of the matrix (say, `corr(x, y)`, `corr(y, z)`, `corr(x, z)`), rather than separating the columns into vectors?

Comment: `cor(mat)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
#gives pairwise
COR = cor(M)
# to get 1 vs 2, 1 vs 3 and 2 vs 3
COR[upper.tri(COR)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combn` to create combination of column names taking 2 at a time, subset the combination from the matrix and then calculate the correlation between them.

```
combn(colnames(mat), 2, function(x) cor(mat[, x[1]], mat[, x[2]]))
#[1]  0.5 -0.5  0.5
```

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(-1L, -1L, 2L, 1L, -2L, 1L, 2L, -1L, -1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("rowA", "rowB", "rowC"), c("x", "y", "z")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
cor_df <- data.frame(vars = row.names(cor(mat)), cor(mat), row.names = NULL)
```